# Can I use PHP in ReactJS to send a form?

Tags: php, reactjs, email

I usually write my code in ReactJS so I have a fully written form element in HTML already. I was then looking up how to connect the form to my email when a user submits & it says to use PHP for that. While learning how to do that it says that I have to rename my .html file to a .php file *but* I am using React so I don't have an html file (besides the one in the public folder).

How do I link my form to my email in ReactJS? Can I still use PHP? Can I write php directly into the HTML section of my ReactJS components?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Normally, you'd write a completely separate php file and inside your ReactJs app you'd use ajax to send your form data to that php script and handle the response. See [here](https://daveceddia.com/ajax-requests-in-react/) for more info